# IOEXCEPTION in C# compact framework when saving image

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, smartphone

I'm saving an image from a web request and something really weird is happening. On roughly half of the 8,000 images I'm downloading I get IOEXCEPTION errors:
ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (5)
INVALID_PARAMETER (87)

Before I save the file using file.open, I check to make sure the file does not exist. The exception is thrown at this line of code:

**fileStream = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);**

Below is the code:

public static bool DownloadFile(string url, string destination)
        {
            bool success = false;

```
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest request = null;
        System.Net.WebResponse response = null;
        Stream responseStream = null;
        FileStream fileStream = null;

        try
        {
            request = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.Timeout = 100000; // 100 seconds
            request.Proxy = System.Net.GlobalProxySelection.GetEmptyWebProxy();
            response = request.GetResponse();

            responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            fileStream = File.Open(destination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
            //fileStream = File.Create(destination);


            // read up to ten kilobytes at a time
            int maxRead = 10240;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[maxRead];
            int bytesRead = 0;
            int totalBytesRead = 0;

            // loop until no data is returned
            while ((bytesRead = responseStream.Read(buffer, 0, maxRead)) > 0)
            {
                totalBytesRead += bytesRead;
                fileStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

            // we got to this point with no exception. Ok.
            success = true;
        }
        catch (System.Net.WebException we)
        {
            // something went terribly wrong.
            success = false;
            //MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            writeErrFile(we.ToString(), url);
            //Debug.WriteLine(exp);
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ie)
        {
            // something went terribly wrong.
            success = false;
            //MessageBox.Show(ie.InnerException.ToString());
            writeErrFile(ie.ToString(), destination + " -- " + url);
            //Debug.WriteLine(exp);
        }
        catch (Exception exp)
        {
            // something went terribly wrong.
            success = false;
            //MessageBox.Show(exp.ToString());
            writeErrFile(exp.ToString(), destination + " -- " + url);
            //Debug.WriteLine(exp);
        }
        finally
        {
            // cleanup all potentially open streams.

            if (null != responseStream)
                responseStream.Close();
            if (null != response)
                response.Close();
            if (null != fileStream)
                fileStream.Close();

        }

        // if part of the file was written and the transfer failed, delete the partial file
        if (!success && File.Exists(destination))
            File.Delete(destination);

        return success;
    }
```

I've been stuck on this for a couple of days. Any help would be appreciated in unimaginable orders of magnitude.

Comment: Here is the error thrown:
System.IO.IOException: IOException
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError()
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor()
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor()
at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile()
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor()
at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor()
at ImageSync.Form1.DownloadFile()
at ImageSync.Form1.button1_Click()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()
at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()
at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()
at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()
at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()

Comment: Try to use the Process Monitor to trace the FileSystem access error.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx

Comment: How do I use the process monitor on Windows Mobile 5?

Comment: This is for a windows mobile 5 device. There are reports that there is a file limit of 1,000 files in a directory, but if I copy the files onto the storage card from my desktop it can read the files just fine, it just won't let me create any new files. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Use file.exists() to check if the file exists and file.create or file.openwrite to write the file.

From your code I can't see how you are checking the file exists.

Comment: This is the code i use to call download file:
if (!File.Exists(fileDownloadName.ToString()))
                            {
                                if(DownloadFile(urlName.ToString(), fileDownloadName.ToString()))
                                    downCount++;
                                else
                                    failCount++;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                existCount++;
                            }